# A monomorphism from an $R$-module to $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity possessing an element $r$ in the singular ideal $Z(R)=$ the set of elements whose annihilators are essential in the module $R_R$, and  let $M$ be a faithful $R$-module. Could it be possible to define an $R$-module *monomorphism* $f:M\longrightarrow  R$?

If the answer is in affirmative, one could prove, first, that $f^{-1}(\mathrm{Ann}_R(r))=\mathrm{Ann}_M(r)$, where $\mathrm{Ann}$ stands for annihilator, whence $\mathrm{Ann}_M(r)$ is essential in $M$. The r.h.s. is easily seen to be a subset of the l.h.s.; for the
reverse, if $\mu \in f^{-1}(\mathrm{Ann}_R(r)$ then $f(r\mu)=0$ and so $r\mu=0$.

Comment: Take $M=R \oplus R$ and such a monomorphism does not exist. Why have you expected this?

Comment: It might help to note that $R$-module monomorphisms $M\rightarrow R$ are also known as the *ideals* of $R$.

Comment: @MooS: There are modules (i.e. torsionless modules) which could be embedded in a direct product of $R_R$.

Comment: So, is your question solved?